# Google Drive Api v3 in Javascript - Sharing files publicly collectively and waiting for the result of the requests

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I have such a function to make the permission of the files publicly available before sharing the selected files.

```
generateFilesPublicly(ids) {
    ids.forEach(id => {
      drive.permissions.create({
        'fileId': id,
        'resource': {
           'value': 'default',
           'type': 'anyone',
           'role': 'reader'
        }
      }).execute();
    });
}
```

After completing these function requests, I need to call the next function to share files. My function to share files should wait for the process to be completed here. But how can I do that? How can I use the promise structure here? And does this function work properly?

What I need;

await generateFilesPublicly(ids);
... next functions

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: In your script, what is `drive`? And, is there a value that is required to return from the function `generateFilesPublicly`?

Comment: You should be able to sleep and have it propagate in that time. Maybe try using a `setTimeout()`?